# Partition and Indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-partitioning, postgresql-10

I have a table partitioned for every quarter. Table name is `data`. In table there is couple of columns but also `date`. `date` is a field which has index on it created:
`create index on data (date);`
Now I am trying to querying the table:

```
justpremium=> EXPLAIN analyze SELECT sum(col_1) FROM data WHERE "date" BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-31';

                                                                          QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=355709.66..355709.67 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=577.072..577.072 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=355709.44..355709.65 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=577.005..578.418 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=354709.44..354709.45 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=573.255..573.256 rows=1 loops=3)
               ->  Append  (cost=0.42..352031.07 rows=1071346 width=8) (actual time=15.286..524.604 rows=837204 loops=3)
                     ->  Parallel Index Scan using data_date_idx on data  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=3)
                           Index Cond: ((date >= '2018-12-01'::date) AND (date <= '2018-12-31'::date))
                     ->  Parallel Seq Scan on data_y2018q4  (cost=0.00..352022.64 rows=1071345 width=8) (actual time=15.282..465.859 rows=837204 loops=3)
                           Filter: ((date >= '2018-12-01'::date) AND (date <= '2018-12-31'::date))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 1479844
 Planning time: 1.437 ms
 Execution time: 578.465 ms
(13 rows)
```

We may see that there is `Parallel Seq Scan on data_y2018q4`. In fact it is normal to me. I have one quarter partition. I am querying third part of the whole partition, so I have seq scan, great.
But now let's query directly partition table:

```
justpremium=> EXPLAIN analyze SELECT sum(col_1) FROM data_y2018q4 WHERE "date" BETWEEN '2018-12-01' AND '2018-12-31';
                                                                                       QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=286475.38..286475.39 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=277.830..277.830 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Gather  (cost=286475.16..286475.37 rows=2 width=32) (actual time=277.760..279.194 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=285475.16..285475.17 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=275.950..275.950 rows=1 loops=3)
               ->  Parallel Index Scan using data_y2018q4_date_idx on data_y2018q4  (cost=0.43..282796.80 rows=1071345 width=8) (actual time=0.022..227.687 rows=837204 loops=3)
                     Index Cond: ((date >= '2018-12-01'::date) AND (date <= '2018-12-31'::date))
 Planning time: 0.187 ms
 Execution time: 279.233 ms
(9 rows)
```

Now I have `Index Scan using data_y2018q4_date_idx` and also time of whole query is two times quicker: `279.233 ms` compared to `578.465 ms`. What is the explanation of this? How force planner to use the index scan when querying `data` table. How to achieve two times better timing?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on v10 or v11. Can you come up with a self contained test case?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I wonder if this is related to [enable_partitionwise_aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-ENABLE-PARTITIONWISE-AGGREGATE) - is that turned on in your environments?

Comment: I am using v10 (10.6) I have no this parameter available.

Comment: I tried with both v10 and v11 with `enable_partitionwise_aggregate` on and off in v11. Never got a sequential scan in my test case...